# Couchbase and mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, memcached, couchbase

With the recent release of MySQL cluster that includes the memcache api, and provides persistency for memcache, can anyone share the benefits of which one to choose?

My initial idea is to use couchbase as a memcache layer between the app and db.

Answer (score 1):

first, as a disclosure, I'm part of the MySQL Cluster team

Speaking specifically for MySQL Cluster, there is a decent blog here that takes you through the design rationale, benefits and implementation:
http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/scalabale-persistent-ha-nosql-memcache-storage-using-mysql-cluster/

There is also a webinar recorded last month that demonstrates how to build a social networking type service with Memcached API and MySQL Cluster (registration required):
http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/on-demand-webinars/display-od-723.html

I don't have any specific comparisons with Couchbase, but I hope the resources above will be useful in helping you determine if MySQL Cluster is right for your project

Comment: Hi, just to be sure I get the ideas right. MySQL cluster can be used to replace memcache nodes. Existing application does not need code changes because "The application sends reads and writes to the memcached process (using the standard Memcached API). This in turn invokes the Memcached Driver for NDB (which is part of the same process) which in turn calls the NDB API for very quick access to the data held in MySQL Cluster’s data nodes".

Comment: "Non-indexed data can reside on disk but indexed columns must always be in memory." Is this a difference btw MySQL and MySQL Cluster? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to answer the same question for myself. I wanted to pick a DB for social application that works intensively with a lot of data and many users. As you can see my needs were not expected to outline some big technical differences between these DBs - after all both are used quite often for such applications.

Anyway, I prepared some load tests based on the scenarios I was interested in. And at the end I run the tests continuously for two days on strong hardware. I would say that more or less both products showed the same amazing performance. I had some crash tests too - dumb cases where I try to eat all the resources and do "stupid" things. On these tests I had lower expectations for Couchbase but it surprised me quite positively and it actually did better job than MongoDB. So, for the needs I had, from technical and architecture perspective I did not find much differences between Couchbase and MySQL Cluster. My advice is to run some tests based on your scenarios and see for yourself.

In my case the choice at the end was based on the license agreement, the statements in the legal notice, the pricing and the community around the product - as a result I picked MySQL Cluster.